# How do I auto update a site RSS feed

Tags: c#, rss, automation

Within a site I am working on, the previous developer put together a very rudementary function to re-create the RSS Feed at the click of a button. I need to be able to have the RSS Feed continuously up-to-date without clicking on the button and running the function.

This is written in C#

Can anyone help me on what to do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Write Your Own .NET RSS Feed in C#](http://www.computorcompanion.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=194)

Check out the section on automation.

Also, [here](http://www.computorcompanion.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=194) are some more [articles](http://www.codersource.net/asp-net/asp-net-advanced/using-rss-feeds-in-asp-net-and-c.aspx).